# How can I avoid multiple model calling at a codeigniter controller functions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, models

Let's assume I have this class at codeigniter:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    function header(){
        $this->load->model("options_model");
        $data['options'] = $this->options_model->get_options();
        $this->load->view("header", $data);
    }

    function content(){
        $this->load->view("content");
        // ...
    }

    function footer(){
        $this->load->model("options_model");
        $data['options'] = $this->options_model->get_options();
        $this->load->view("footer", $data);
    }

    function index(){
        $this->header();
        $this->content();
        $this->footer();
    }
}
```

As you see, I repeated calling options_model and the method get_options at both header and footer. Then, at index I called header and footer. How can I avoid repeating methods at this cases. Or what is the best way for cases like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can call your model in `application/config/autoload.php` it will include in all your project as

```
$autoload['model'] = array('options_model');
```

If you want to upload under single controller. then you can call it inside construct

```
 public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("options_model"); // load it here??
    }
```

Add correct spelling of `functin` it is `function`

Comment: Thanks @Saty. I know that I can use autoload.php But I wonders about calling get_options() in multiple functions. then I call them at one. if there is a way to avoid calling it in both header and footer to reduce the load at server and the number of executing the query at model.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid calling model (get_options()) in both header I would prefer you to create custom helper for it and directly call it in view.

read more about it at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: The link you've provided points to an old documentation. EllisLab is not in charge anymore and the new docs are at codeigniter.com

Comment: edthe major problem is not with calling the model itself, but with calling a the method get_optins() twice. I think that the query executed twice. and I would like to avoid that.